# VBA - How to use a VLookup to retrieve totals from a dynamic changing pivot table

Tags: excel, vba, pivot, vlookup

I am pretty new at using VBA with Vlookups on Pivot tables so any help is appreciated here.  I have a set of account numbers and names in a string in my first sheet that I need to retrieve totals for that I have in a pivot table in a separate sheet.

For example:

My first sheet "MOM YTD Totals" has the following content in cells A11:A600 (example is shorter but sometimes this list will be more than 600)

4-50000  Other Miscellaneous

4-50001  National

4-50002  Media

4-50003  Sponsors

and so on...

I would like to fill contents in B11:B600 with amount totals that match these account numbers and names however the pivot table ranges in size and I don't know how many columns it will have each month.

The second sheet "NW_pivot" has the pivot table I created starting at cell Q6 (Q -column with the account to lookup) and the Grand Total (last column in the pivot table) is the amount I want pulled into the first sheets column B.

[image: Example pivot table]

and so on...

Does anyone have any tips on the easiest way to do this possibly?  I have tried many variations with the code below but think I am just way off here and a vlookup should be used but I don't know how to even start with one in a pivot table so I apologize.

Sub MatchAccountTotals()

```
dim i As Long
dim j As Long
dim lastrow1 As Long
dim lastrow2 As Long
dim lastcol1 As Long
dim accountName As String

lastrow1=sheets("MOM YTD Totals").range("A" & Rows.Count).end(xlUp).row

For i=11 to lastrow1    
    accountName=sheets("MOM YTD Totals - All Entities").cells(i, "A").value


 Sheets("NW_Pivot").Activate
 lastrow2=Sheets("NW_Pivot").range("Q" & Rows.Count).end(xlUp).row
 lastcol1=Sheets("NW_Pivot").Cells(6,columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column


For j=6 To lastrow2

if sheets("NW_Pivot").cells(j,"Q").value=accountName

    sheets("NW_Pivot").cells(j,"lastcol")).copy

    sheets("MOM YTD Totals").activate

    sheets("MOM YTD Totals").cells(i,"D").select

    activesheet.paste

End If

   Next j
   application.CutCopyMode=False
   Next i

sheets("MOM YTD Totals").Activate
sheets("MOM YTD Totals").range("A1").select
```

End Sub

Any tips are greatly welcomed, thank you!

Comment: Have you considered using worksheet formulae instead of VBA? GetPivotData would be a great candidate to access data values in pivot tables. Maybe you can combine that with VBA.

Comment: Thank you, yes I will try this and see how it goes.